# Url query params

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Vue 2.4.4. I have been searching for gettin URL query params, and most places following are suggested:

```
this.$route.query.test
```

$route is undefined do you need to do something special to get this working?

---

I found a solution thanks to tanathos:

```
var router = new VueRouter({
mode: 'history',
routes: []
});

var index = new Vue({
el: '#index',
router,
mounted: function () {

    alert(this.$route.query.test);
```

Comment: Did you register the router in your main.js with `import VueRouter from 'vue-router';` and `Vue.use(VueRouter);`?

Comment: No. You have a sample that is not type script?

Comment: I have updated main post with image of registration.

Comment: Thanks you comment got me to next step. I updated my main post with answer. Can you add an answer so you can be credited?

Comment: @ThomasSegato that is not Typescript. Next time read the fine manual ~ https://router.vuejs.org/installation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main.js (or anyway, the entry point of your application) you'll need first to import the VueRouter:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
```

and use it to extend Vue:

```
Vue.use(VueRouter);
```

At this point you'll need to crete the real instance of the router, configuring it according to your application's needs:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  /* your configuration options */
});
```

The you inject this instance in the Vue root instance:

```
new Vue({
  router,
  /* etc... */
});
```

At this point the $router and $route object should be available from any Vue component.